# nodemon nodejs and mongoose: cyclic dependency detected

Tags: node.js, mongoose

[image]

Create app with node and react but stuck from last few hours and not finding any solutions to this error

app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: More context is needed.`package.json` file would help.

Comment: I have solved this error.
It may be dependency conflict or dependency version older one